# Going around the many-to-many relationship in Spring boot, but no new entity is created

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot to construct a database using AWS RDS as well. I want to track down how many stars a user gives to different products. I learnt to go around the many-to-many relationship by creating a table connecting two one-to-many other tables. For this reason, I have created the following tables:

[image]

When a user rates a product, an api is called through the put command in order to track down which user(uid) rates which product(pid). When the product(pid) is not rated by anyone, a rate_item is created that contains the pid and also the uid. However, when another user (with a different uid) rates the same product (same pid), **the rate_item is updated**, which is a problem becausse supposedly, a new row containing the same pid and a different uid should be created, as seen in the following (user with "uid 1" has already rated the same product and when user with "uid 2" rates the same product, the entity gets updated, but not like a new entity is created):
[image]

ProductEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pid",nullable = false)
    private Integer pid;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="theme", nullable = false)
    private String theme;
    @Column(name="color", nullable = false)
    private String color;
    @Column(name="sizeZero", nullable = true)
    private String sizeZero;
    @Column(name="sizeOne", nullable = true)
    private String sizeOne;
    @Column(name="sizeTwo", nullable = true)
    private String sizeTwo;
    @Column(name="sizeThree", nullable = true)
    private String sizeThree;
    @Column(name="description",nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false)
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(name = "price",nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "stock",nullable = false)
    private Integer stock;

    public ProductEntity(CreateProductData createProductData) {
        this.pid = createProductData.getPid();
        this.name = createProductData.getName();
        this.theme =createProductData.getTheme();
        this.color=createProductData.getColor();
        this.sizeZero=createProductData.getSizeZero();
        this.sizeOne =createProductData.getSizeOne();
        this.sizeTwo =createProductData.getSizeTwo();
        this.sizeThree =createProductData.getSizeThree();
        this.description =createProductData.getDescription();
        this.imageUrl = createProductData.getImageUrl();
        this.price = createProductData.getPrice();
        this.stock = createProductData.getStock();
    }
    public ProductEntity(){

    }

    public Integer getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Integer pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(String productType) {
        this.theme = productType;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getSizeZero() {
        return sizeZero;
    }

    public void setSizeZero(String sizeZero) {
        this.sizeZero = sizeZero;
    }
    public String getSizeOne() {
        return sizeOne;
    }

    public void setSizeOne(String smallSize) {
        this.sizeOne = smallSize;
    }

    public String getSizeTwo() {
        return sizeTwo;
    }

    public void setSizeTwo(String mediumSize) {
        this.sizeTwo = mediumSize;
    }

    public String getSizeThree() {
        return sizeThree;
    }

    public void setSizeThree(String largeSize) {
        this.sizeThree = largeSize;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

UserEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="uid",nullable = false)
    private Integer uid;
    @Column(name="username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "firebase_uid", nullable = false)
    private String firebaseUid;
    @Column(name= "emailVerified", nullable = false,columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private Boolean emailVerified=false;

    @Column(name="subscribed", nullable = false)
    private Boolean subscribed;

    public UserEntity(UserEntity tempUserEntity){
        this.uid=tempUserEntity.getUid();
        this.firebaseUid=tempUserEntity.getFirebaseUid();
        this.email=tempUserEntity.getEmail();
    }

    public UserEntity(CreateFirebaseUserData createFirebaseUserData){
        this.username=createFirebaseUserData.getUsername();
        this.email=createFirebaseUserData.getEmail();
        this.password=createFirebaseUserData.getPassword();
        this.firebaseUid= createFirebaseUserData.getFirebaseUid();
        this.subscribed=createFirebaseUserData.getSubscribed();
    }

    public UserEntity(){

    }

    public Integer getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(Integer uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirebaseUid() {
        return firebaseUid;
    }

    public void setFirebaseUid(String firebaseUid) {
        this.firebaseUid = firebaseUid;
    }

    public Boolean getEmailVerified() {
        return emailVerified;
    }

    public void setEmailVerified(Boolean emailVerified) {
        this.emailVerified = emailVerified;
    }

    public Boolean getSubscribed() {
        return subscribed;
    }

    public void setSubscribed(Boolean subscribed) {
        this.subscribed = subscribed;
    }
}
```

RatingEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Rating")
public class ProductsRatedByUserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="pruid")
    private Integer pruid;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pid",nullable = false)
    private ProductEntity product;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uid",nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;
    @Column
    private Integer starsGiven;
    @Column(name="total_stars", nullable = false)
    private Integer totalStars;
    @Column(name="total_num_of_users_who_rated", nullable = false)
    private Integer totalNumOfUsersWhoRated;
    @Column(name="average_stars")
    private BigDecimal averageStars;

    public ProductsRatedByUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity, ProductEntity productEntity, Integer numOfStars){
        this.product=productEntity;
        this.user=userEntity;
        this.starsGiven=numOfStars;
        this.totalStars=numOfStars;
        this.totalNumOfUsersWhoRated=1;
        this.averageStars=BigDecimal.valueOf(this.getTotalStars()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(this.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated()));
    }

    public ProductsRatedByUserEntity(ProductEntity product,UserEntity user,Integer numOfStars,Integer newTotalNumOfStars, Integer newTotalNumberOfUsers, BigDecimal averageStars){
        this.product=product;
        this.user=user;
        this.starsGiven=numOfStars;
        this.totalStars=newTotalNumOfStars;
        this.totalNumOfUsersWhoRated=newTotalNumberOfUsers;
        this.averageStars=averageStars;
    }


    public ProductsRatedByUserEntity(){

    }


    public Integer getPruid() {
        return pruid;
    }

    public void setPruid(Integer plbuid) {
        this.pruid = plbuid;
    }

    public ProductEntity getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(ProductEntity product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getStarsGiven() {
        return starsGiven;
    }

    public void setStarsGiven(Integer starsGiven) {
        this.starsGiven = starsGiven;
    }

    public Integer getTotalStars() {
        return totalStars;
    }

    public void setTotalStars(Integer totalStars) {
        this.totalStars = totalStars;
    }

    public Integer getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated() {
        return totalNumOfUsersWhoRated;
    }

    public void setTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated(Integer totalNumOfUsersWhoLiked) {
        this.totalNumOfUsersWhoRated = totalNumOfUsersWhoLiked;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAverageStars() {
        return averageStars;
    }

    public void setAverageStars(BigDecimal averageStars) {
        this.averageStars = averageStars;
    }



}
```

Api:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ProductApi {
    private ProductService productService;
    private ProductsRatedByUserService productsRatedByUserService;
    @Autowired
    public ProductApi(ProductService productService,ProductsRatedByUserService productsRatedByUserService){
        this.productService=productService;
        this.productsRatedByUserService=productsRatedByUserService;
    }
    @PutMapping("/product/rating/{pid}/{numOfStars}")
    public ProductsRatedByUserResponseDto updateRating(@PathVariable Integer pid, @PathVariable Integer numOfStars, JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData=new FirebaseUserData(jwtAuthenticationToken);
        ProductsRatedByUserDetail productsRatedByUserDetail=productsRatedByUserService.updateProductRating(pid,numOfStars,firebaseUserData);
        return new ProductsRatedByUserResponseDto(productsRatedByUserDetail);
    }
}
```

RatingServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@Component
public class ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl implements ProductsRatedByUserService {
    public ProductsRatedByUserRepository productsRatedByUserRepository;
    public ProductRepository productRepository;
    public UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl(ProductsRatedByUserRepository productsRatedByUserRepository,ProductRepository productRepository,UserRepository userRepository){
        this.productsRatedByUserRepository=productsRatedByUserRepository;
        this.productRepository=productRepository;
        this.userRepository=userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductsRatedByUserDetail updateProductRating(Integer pid, Integer numOfStars, FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        if(!productRepository.existsById(pid)){
            throw new ProductFoundByIdException();
        }
        UserEntity userEntity=userRepository.findUserEntityByEmail(firebaseUserData.getEmail());
        ProductEntity productEntity =productRepository.findById(pid).orElse(null);
        //check if the product has been rated by *any user*
        //If no, we need to create an entity
        if(!productsRatedByUserRepository.existsByProduct(productEntity)){
            ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntity=new ProductsRatedByUserEntity(userEntity, productEntity, numOfStars);
            ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntityReturned=productsRatedByUserRepository.save(productsRatedByUserEntity);
            System.out.println("the product has been rated by *any user*");
            return new ProductsRatedByUserDetail(productsRatedByUserEntityReturned);
        }
        //If yes, we update the entity from there
        else {
            //if the product has been rated by this very user
            if (productsRatedByUserRepository.existsByUserAndProduct(userEntity, productEntity)) {
                ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntity = productsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByUserAndProduct(userEntity, productEntity);
                productsRatedByUserEntity.setTotalStars(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalStars() - productsRatedByUserEntity.getStarsGiven() + numOfStars);
                productsRatedByUserEntity.setStarsGiven(numOfStars);
                productsRatedByUserEntity.setAverageStars(BigDecimal.valueOf(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalStars()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated())));
                ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntityReturned = productsRatedByUserRepository.save(productsRatedByUserEntity);
                System.out.println("the product has been rated by this very user");
                return new ProductsRatedByUserDetail(productsRatedByUserEntityReturned);
            } else {
                //The product has not been rated by this very user
                ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntity = productsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByProduct(productEntity);
                int newTotalNumOfStars = (productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalStars() + numOfStars);
                int newTotalNumberOfUsers = productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated() + 1;
                productsRatedByUserEntity.setUser(userEntity);
                System.out.println("The product has not been rated by this very user");
                return new ProductsRatedByUserDetail(productsRatedByUserRepository.save(new ProductsRatedByUserEntity(productEntity, userEntity, numOfStars, newTotalNumOfStars, newTotalNumberOfUsers, BigDecimal.valueOf(newTotalNumOfStars).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(newTotalNumberOfUsers)))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RatingServiceInterface:

```
public interface ProductsRatedByUserService {
    ProductsRatedByUserDetail updateProductRating(Integer pid, Integer numOfStars, FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData) throws ProductFoundByIdException;

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProductsRatedByUserRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductsRatedByUserEntity,Integer> {
    boolean existsByProduct(ProductEntity product);
    ProductsRatedByUserEntity findTopByProduct(ProductEntity product);
    boolean existsByUserAndProduct(UserEntity userEntity, ProductEntity product);
    ProductsRatedByUserEntity findTopByUserAndProduct(UserEntity userEntity, ProductEntity product);
}
```

I will really appreciate anyone who can help me with this! I've been stuck for a whole day! I don't want to use the many-to-many annotation because it seems a bit messy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake. In my RatingEntity code, the getter and setter are erroneous. There's some typos there. It should be

```
public Integer getPruid() {
        return pruid;
    }

    public void setPruid(Integer pruid) {
        this.pruid = pruid;
    }
```